# Problema com Allegro 4 e C++

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, allegro

Estou tentando criar um jogo em `Allegro 4`, porém estou tendo problemas com um metódo, mais especificamente com um atributo `BITMAP`. O programa compila mas para de funcionar logo em seguida. Segue o codigo:

```
#ifndef INSTANCE_H
#define INSTANCE_H

#include "global.h"

class Instance{
public:
    Instance(bool random);
    void setTexture(string local);
    int getPositionX();
    int getPositionY();
    void drawOnBuffer(BITMAP *buff);
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    BITMAP *texture;
};

#endif
```

Ao chamar o método `setTexture`, o programa para de funcionar. Acredito que o problema esteja ocorrendo por causa do atribuito texture ser um ponteiro, mas sou iniciante em orientação a objetos e ainda não consegui resolver. A implementação que eu fiz foi o seguinte:

```
void Instance::setTexture(string local){
    texture = load_bitmap(&local[0], NULL);
}
```

Na main, eu crio o objeto e passo o nome do `arquivo bitmap` para ser aberto:

```
Instance pokeball(true);
pokeball.setTexture("pokeball.bmp");
```

Lembrando que o problema está ao atribuir um valor ao atributo texture. Sempre que removo ele do código, tudo funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se não é isso:

`void Instance::setTexture(string local){
    texture = load_bitmap(local.c_str(), NULL);
}`

Assim você passa a `std::string` "traduzida" para o `const char *`